# Change class back to normal after blur() if form field is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this jquery script set up so that when a key is pressed down it checks if the password meets the requirements, but if I set focus on the form field and then leave it (Without entering anything) the script still applies those .addClass functions and instead it should revert back to normal by applying .removeClass('red-icon green-icon'); from the selectors #rule1, #rule2, #rule3. How do I fix this?

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
        // Password length check
        $("#password").keyup(checkPassword);
        $("#password").blur(checkPassword);

  });

  function checkPassword() {
        var password = $("#password").val();


        //check if field not empty
        if(password.length < 0) {
              $("#rule1, #rule2, #rule3").removeClass('red-icon green-icon');
        } else {

              // validate number
              if(password.match(/[0-9]/)) {
                    $("#rule3").removeClass('fa-close red-icon');
                    $("#rule3").addClass('fa-check green-icon');
              } else {
                    $("#rule3").removeClass('fa-check green-icon');
                    $("#rule3").addClass('fa-close red-icon');
              }

              //validate capital letter
              if(password.match(/[A-Z]/)) {
                    $("#rule1").removeClass('fa-close red-icon');
                    $("#rule1").addClass('fa-check green-icon');
              } else {
                    $("#rule1").removeClass('fa-check green-icon');
                    $("#rule1").addClass('fa-close red-icon');
              }

              //validate password length
              if(password.length >= 8) {
                    $("#rule2").removeClass('fa-close red-icon');
                    $("#rule2").addClass('fa-check green-icon');
              } else {
                    $("#rule2").removeClass('fa-check green-icon');
                    $("#rule2").addClass('fa-close red-icon');
              }
        }
  }
```

**EDIT:**

Ok I now changed the way of the script, so now if on blur it detects that the field is empty it will change the class of selector #rule4 like so :

```
  // check if field is not blank
              if(password.length === 0) {
                    $("#rule4").removeClass('fa-check green-icon');
                    $("#rule4").addClass('fa-close red-icon');
              } else {
                    $("#rule4").removeClass('fa-close red-icon');
                    $("#rule4").addClass('fa-check green-icon');
              }
```

But it then also triggers other conditions. How to make it trigger only the condition `if(password.length === 0)` ?

**EDIT#2:**
It appears it also allows me to submit my form even if these requirements are not met. Is there a function to disable the submit button to prevent this?

Comment: Logically, If I am leaving the password field blank, then it should display some error message over there..

Comment: Shouldn't the condition be `if(password.length === 0) {` instead of `if(password.length < 0) {`?

Comment: `But it then also triggers other conditions` Do you mean the first `if` condition is reached **and** the first `else` too? Because that's not possible

Comment: It triggers the conditions with comments above them : //validate capital letter, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to disable your submit button give it an id.. (id="something")
then use this statement to disable-

```
$("#something").disable();
```

and this to enable wherever required-

```
$("#something").enable();
```

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
if(password.length < 0) {
```

is always `false` since length can't be negative. should be:

```
if(password.length == 0) {
```

Comment: Changed it, but now I have another problem... check my edit